# Good practice when updating a CoreData entity from another entity

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am working with an API that will return me another instance of an object that already exists in CoreData, but with the updated properties. What is a good practice of doing this?

I have been creating a new instance with `insertNewObject(forEntityName:into:)` then replacing the locally fetched instance, setup the new relationships between entities (because those relationships were broken when the local object was replaced by the updated object, since the updated object has these properties left out), and then call save on the `managedObjectContext`.

The problem with this is that the object is saved, but the properties that I manually try to change are not. For example:

```
let oldObject = ...
block_calling_the_backend(receives newObject from completionClosure(response = true/false, newObject?)) {
   if response == true {
     let parent = oldObject.parent
     oldObject.parent = nil
     parent.child = nil
     oldObject = newObject
     newObject.parent = parent
     parent.child = newObject

    do {
      try managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch {
      print("Something went wrong when saving the context.")
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried deleting the fetched object from the context and then tried to save, but then all data is lost. What is actually a good practice of doing this?

P.S. Everything is saved when I do the replacing manually, property by property.